# Maximum of a Object-Parameter in an Object-List

Tags: c#, list, class

I want to ask, wheter there is a short form for finding the maximum of a parameter of a certain object-list in a `List` or an `Array`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Car car1 = new Car(120);
        Car car2 = new Car(140);
        Car car3 = new Car(100);
        List<Car> cars = new List<Car> { car1, car2, car3 };

        // THIS I WANT TO SHORTEN ██████████
        // ▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼
        // Find car with maximum Power
        double max = 0;
        foreach (Car car in cars)
            if (car.power > max)
                max = car.power;
        // ▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲
        // █████████████████████████████████

        Console.WriteLine("The maximum power is = " + max);
    }

    public class Car
    {
        public double power; // Horsepower of the car
        public Car (double power)
        {
            this.power = power;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for something easy maybe like `cars.findMax(car => car.power)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ for this:

```
var max = cars
    .Select(c => c.power)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
    .Max();
```

- `.Select(c => c.power)` will select the `power` property from each object.
- `.Max()` will throw an `InvalidOperationException` error if there is nothing in `cars`, so we set a default to `0` with `.DefaultIfEmpty(0)`
- `.Max()`, as it sounds like, will return the maximum value.

If you are absolutely 100% sure that that `cars` will never be empty, then you could also skip all of that and just do this:

```
var max = cars.Max(c => c.power);
```

Comment: nice! also worked, if  I take a method maybe like `getPower()` instead of a parameter like `power`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ for this

```
 var max = cars.Max(i => i.power);
```